# Check if value is assigned

Tags: javascript

How to check if a value has been assigned to a variable?

I start with

```
var val = '';
```

//then later I assign a value to `val`. So before `val` is used anywhere I need to be sure if there is a value assigned to `val`. How do I do this?

```
if (typeof name !== "undefined"){
     //a value is defined
}
```

or

```
if (name != null){
   //a value is defined
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't they both break - based on your initial sentence - if the value of `undefined` or `null` was explicitly and deliberately assigned to those variables?

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you. Values of `undefined` or `null` will not be assigned deliberately.

Comment: @naomik Thanks. See my edit. `var val = '';` Then later I assign a value to val. So before val is used anywhere I need to be sure if there is a value assigned to val. How do I do this?